# Generating and displaying images in grid in Silverlight

Tags: image, silverlight-4.0, datagrid, grid, shapes

I want to develop an webpage like Google Images in Silverlight.
The difference is the images are generated from my DSL.

The webpage shows different images in grid and allows users to pick one.
The webpage then shows similar images to this.

1. Should I use Grid panel or DataGrid? And how do I handle double click on cells?
2. Should I generate my DSL to Shapes or Image? What are the pros and cons?
   Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually pretty simple, all you need to do is use a **data template** for the column in your **datagrid**.

```
<sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
   <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Width="80">
      <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
           <Image Width="240" Height="180" Source="http://www.yourimage.com/images/myimage.png" /> 
         </DataTemplate>
      </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
</sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
```

**Optional:** If you need to **change the image via code** rather than inline like this then in place of the Image XAML element put a stackpanel that calls a function in your code-behind, which returns an image.

```
<StackPanel Loaded="StackPanel_Loaded"></StackPanel>
```